# Raspbian (Debian) - Route some traffic though eth0 and some through tun0 (OpenVPN)

Tags: networking, routing, raspbian, openvpn, vpn

I am trying to configure a Pi running Raspbian to route some traffic through tun0 (OpenVPN). The sole program that I want routing traffic through tun0 allows me to specify the interface it uses, so this part isn't an issue.

What I am having more trouble with is making traffic from any other program route through eth0 while OpenVPN is connected.

Thanks for the advice in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a specific program to use the VPN, then I believe the keyword you're looking for is "split-tunnel."  Split Tunnel means that specific traffic will use the VPN, usually controlled via routing tables, while other network traffic will use the local networks default gateway.  I do this for my work VPN where email and other work traffic uses the VPN, but my Facebook and Google traffic never touches my employers/VPN network.

If you have control over the OpenVPN server you can update it's configuration to only send specific routes to the Pi, and avoid becoming the default route.

You can also configure this on the Client/Pi side by either adjusting the OVPN file *before* importing it, or simply adjusting the Pi's networking configuration using normal Debian commands like these:

```
$ sudo ip route delete default
$ sudo ip route add default via X.Y.Z.IP
```